# Installed OpenSuse and I can't Reboot either

Tags: grub

I installed OpenSuse last night, and everything seemed to go alright until I went to try it out and couldn't get into my laptop as grub was asking for the Master Key.

What can I do, I'm worried as my laptop is less than a year old and by the looks of things this is happening to a lot of people.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some context. Do you see a grub menu or do you just get this message? Does the message appear after selecting something  in grub? What? Do you have other options? Do you know what the Master Key is? do you have an encrypted disk on this laptop? Is there another installed operating system? You say "by the looks of things", what things? Have you found other people with the same issue? Maybe linking to those posts would help? The more you tell us, the better our chances of being able to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I get the following message and when I press escape it takes me to  THE next page Grub and I don't know what to do next, apparently other people who have used the OpenSUSE Leap 15.3 are having similar problems.

[image: Attempting To Decrypt Key]

[![Grub]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DW7s.png)